# Jquery Table row doesn't break

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to build a table into a div by using jQuery and the code is as follow. However, although new tr are appended into the table, the resulting table does not come out with 3 rows but all tr are clumping in one row. .scoreboard is a div.

```
function printScoreboard(){


    var $theTable = $('<table>');
        $theTable.css({'border':'solid black 2px'})
                 .addClass('scoreTable');

    var score = [];
    score.push({label:"Total Question: ", value:totalSec});
    score.push({label:"Right Question: ", value:rightQuest});
    score.push({label:"Wrong Question: ", value:wrongQuest});


    for(var idx = 0 ; idx < 3 ; idx ++){

        var currentArray = score[idx];
        $theTable.append('<tr>').append($("<td>").text(currentArray.label)
                                            ,$("<td>").text(currentArray.value));
    }

    console.log("print score board");

    $('.scoreBoard').empty();
    $('.scoreBoard').append($theTable);

}
```

http://i46.tinypic.com/jjwyg9.png

It could have been 3-row table but somehow doesn't work.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `append` returns the $theTable, not what it appended. Therefore, the `<tr>` is appended to the table, then a `<td>` is appended to the table, then another `<td>` is appended to the table. The net effect is three `<tr>` elements with no content followed by 6 `<td>` elements.

You need to change it to:

```
$theTable.append($('<tr>').append($("<td>").text(currentArray.label)
                                    ,$("<td>").text(currentArray.value)));
```